# Unable to Start ORACLE NOSQL database

Tags: java, oracle, nosql, port, oracle-nosql

This error is showing, I checked it in many places but unable to find the solution.

I am unable to start kvlite, other system has the same configuration of java and KVLITE. Its returning `NullPointerExcepetion`.

**KVLITE version:** *kv-ce-4.5.12.zip*

**JAVA VERSION:**

- openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

**The Error:**

```
KVLite: exception in start: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.read(TCPEndpoint.java:557)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.read(LiveRef.java:292)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2.readExternal(UnicastRef2.java:78)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObject.readObject(RemoteObject.java:455)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:154)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:469)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:301)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing java version to "1.8.0_231" worked for me.